# JavaScript returning ObjectObject with no fields returning as expected { a: 2, b: 2, c: 1 }

Tags: javascript

I am constructing a reduce function that accepts an array, a callback, and an initial value and returns a single value. The function satisfies 2/3 of the following conditions: should not mutate the input array, should sum up an array, and should create a "totals" object from an array.

```
function reduce(array, callback, num) {
  let sum = 0;
  let totals;
  for ( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += num + array[i];
  }
  return sum
   array.forEach(function(ele, index){
    totals = callback(totals, ele);
  });
  return totals;
}
```

I've satisfied all these conditions except the final one. I get the following error after running my code where my reduce function fails to "create a "totals" object from an array":

```
expected 'expected
  '0[object Object]a[object Object]b[object Object]c[object Object]a[object Object]b'
to deeply equal
  { a: 2, b: 2, c: 1 }.
```

Any input here would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the `return` keyword ends the function. Writing code after `return sum` is useless

Comment: A function should not have more than one `Unconditional returns`. You never get any value of `totals` from this function because the return of `sum` executed first.

Comment: Then next issue is overwriting `totals` every iteration of the loop after you remove the premature return

Comment: @charlietfl why would that be an issue? That's how `reduce` works. Your callback returns a value, and that value is passed to the next call of your callback and so on

Comment: CSWR (Crawl, stand, walk, run). There's no shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `return` keyword ends the function. So, writing any code past that `return sum` would have no effect at all. And in fact, you don't need that return, nor the loop above it:

```js
function reduce(array, callback, totals) {
  // By default, if totals is empty, reduce uses the first element as a base
  if (typeof totals === "undefined" && array.length > 0) {
    totals = array[0];
    array = array.slice(1);
  }

  array.forEach(function(ele, index){
    totals = callback(totals, ele);
  });
  
  return totals;
}


console.log( reduce([1, 2, 3], (sum, v) => sum + v)    ); // 6
console.log( reduce([1, 2, 3], (sum, v) => sum + v, 3) ); // 9
```

Comment: Thanks you blex. Quick question, why does array.slice start at 1 instead of 0, the first element?

Comment: @Codestudio `array.slice(1)` actually creates a new Array from the original one, but starting from index `1` because we want to remove the first one (we already took it by doing `totals = array[0]`)

Comment: The default behavior of `reduce` if you don't provide a `totals` parameter, is to use the first element as a starting value, and it will only call your callback on the rest of the array (not the first one)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but your code makes no sense. Here's why:

```
function reduce(array, callback, num) {
  let sum = 0;
  let totals;

  // Problem one - you are hardcoding behaviour instead of 
  // using a callback which is normally supposed to inject the reducing logics
  for ( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += num + array[i];
  }
  return sum // after that line all the code is a deadcode
  // as the return command terminates your reduce function 
  // and returns sum
   array.forEach(function(ele, index){
    totals = callback(totals, ele);
  // as I said this is the dead code. Anyways pay attention that
  // totals variable is instantiated but undefined. What are you planning 
  // to achieve by providing it to the callback function?
  });
  return totals;
}
```

And here's my implementation of the standard JS API Array.prototype.reduce function:

```
function myReduce (cb, initialValue) {
 if (!Array.isArray(this) || (!this.length && !initialValue))
   throw TypeError;

 // making a copy of the original array to prevent
 // it from being mutated by a callback
 const array = [...this];

 // if no initial value is provided, we take the first element
 // of array instead
 let acc = initialValue || array[0];

 // if no initialValue is provided we start iteration from 1
 // else the iterations starts from 0
 for (let i = Number(!initialValue); i < array.length; i++)
    acc = cb (acc, array[i], i, array);

 return acc;
}

// here's what you supposedly are trying to achieve:
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

// hereinafter I will use Function.prototype.call 
// to bind the array to myReduce function
console.log(myReduce.call(myArray, (acc, cur) => acc + cur)); // => 15

// And more advanced example of a simple array-to-object mapper:
const myArray2 = [
  {id: 0, email: 'user0@co.cc'},
  {id: 1, email: 'user1@co.cc'},
  {id: 2, email: 'user2@co.cc'},
];

console.log(myReduce.call(
  myArray2, // this
  (acc, {email, id}) => ({...acc, [id]:  email}), // cb
  {} // initial state
)); // => Object {0: "user0@co.cc", 1: "user1@co.cc", 2: "user2@co.cc"}
```

Hopefully that will be helpful. Good luck!